# $_FILES is empty on Strato server

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I have got some frustating problems facing a file upload with a php script. The problem is that my script is working on my local xampp server. When I transfer it to my strato host server it won't work anymore. There is no error output. During debugging i recognized that the $_FILES array is completly empty.. there is nothing in it.

`print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($_FILES)` display the following when the form is submitted:

```
Array
(
    [submit] => 
)

Array
(
)
```

My php.ini contains the following configuration parameters which are relevant for file uploads (validated by `phpinfo()`):

```
file_uploads = On;
memory_limit = 128M;
post_max_size = 8M;
upload_max_filesize = 128M;
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp;
```

The files I tried to upload did not exceed the limit of 8MB `post_max_size`.

My form looks like this:

```
<form action="bilder.php" target="_self" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept="image/*"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
    <button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger">delete files</button>
</form>
```

There is nothing surrounding it but the body element.

My php script from `bilder.php` which already includes many debugging outputs looks like this:

```
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Das Upload-Verzeichnis
$upload_folder = 'uploads/bilder/';

echo "<pre>";
print_r(realpath($upload_folder)."\n");

echo isset($_POST["submit"]);
echo isset($_POST["delete"]); 

print_r($_POST);

echo ("FILES=empty? ".empty($_FILES)."\n");

print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";
if (!empty($_FILES) && isset($_POST["submit"]))
{   
    echo "file will be uploaded";

    $new_path = uploadPicture("file", $upload_folder);

    if ($new_path) {
        $uploadMessage .= '<p class="alert alert-success"> File successfully uploaded </p>';    
    }
}
```

Where the function `uploadPicture` checks and uploads the file and returns the path where it has been saved on the server. This is a standard script I copied from somewhere else. This should not cause my problem because it is never executed on the strato server.

There must be something wrong with my strato server configuration, but I can't figure out what the problem is. The `php.ini` seems wright. Does anybody have an idea?